# Sandbox: trying to write I2C in the title with LaTeX: \$\text{I}^2\text{C}\$

Tags: discussion, latex

In the message body, this would produce the sought result: \$\text{I}^2\text{C}\$

How about in the title?

Works as well.  Great.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with the HTML `<sup>` superscript tag, which is generally preferred because it renders more quickly and reduces page size:

```
I<sup>2</sup>C
```

produces

> I<sup>2</sup>C

This (like Markdown) does not work in the question title.

Comment: I tried it and doesn't work in the title.

Comment: @clabacchio - Oops, looks like you're right.  Edited!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Unicode: I²C

I have an [AutoHotkey Hotstring](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) to do this automatically:

```
::i2c::I²C
```

(and also [many](https://gist.github.com/823381) [other](https://gist.github.com/876629) things)

Comment: ALT+2 isn't easier? It works with the international keyboard layout (at least to me). And I think it's cleaner than LaTeX, because it changes the font.

Comment: @clabacchio: Not sure what you mean by that. ALT+2? Changing the font?

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning ALT GR+2 or CTRL+ALT+2

Comment: @clabacchio: Well, typing `i2c` is certainly going to be easier than typing `<Shift>+I <Ctrl>+<Alt>+2 <Shift>+C`.  Ctrl+Alt+2 doesn't do anything for me anyway.  Still don't know what you mean by changing font.

Comment: Well yes, but since it works in  the PC I'm using, I find easier to press ALTGr+2 than using a script...²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²²² :)

Comment: @clabacchio: Typing things naturally and having them autocorrected is much easier than memorizing keyboard combinations.  :)  I guess if you have to type lots of superscript 2s in a row, that would be better, though.